# How to clear() input fields by overwriting cy.type() command in Cypress

Tags: javascript, command, cypress

For my Cypress e2e tests:

Everytime I have to type something in an input, I have to manually clear the input by calling `clear()` before `type()`

I have to clear because there are other negative tests before this step which might have left invalid data in those fields.

How can I overwrite the `type()` command to `clear()` the input everytime before I use the `type()` method

```
cy.get('@firstname')
  .clear()
  .type('John')
  .get('@lastname')
  .clear()
  .type('Doe')
  .get('@email')
  .clear()
  .type('john.doe@email.com');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cypress's custom commands allows for overwriting existing commands
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Overwrite-Existing-Commands

Also, the clear() command is just an alias for .type('{selectall}{backspace}');
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clear.html#Syntax

So what you could do is overwrite the type command to always type {selectall}{backspace} before anything else is typed.

Heres an example you could add to commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("type", (originalFn, element, text, options) => {
  const clearedText = `{selectall}{backspace}${text}`;

  return originalFn(element, clearedText, options);
});
```

This will change the logging to include the extra commands. If you prefer the logging be like the original type command you could customize it a bit.

```
Cypress.Commands.overwrite("type", (originalFn, element, text, options) => {
  const clearedText = `{selectall}{backspace}${text}`;

  options = { ...options, log: false };

  Cypress.log({
    $el: element,
    name: "type",
    message: text,
  });

  return originalFn(element, clearedText, options);
});
```

Edit:

Since the suggestion above does not handle date inputs and others what I would do is just create a new cypress command that calls the clear command then the type command sequentially.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("clearThenType", { prevSubject: true }, (subject, text) => {
    cy.wrap(subject).clear().type(text);
  }
);
```

Example:

```
cy.get('@firstname')
  .clearThenType('John')
  .get('@lastname')
  .clearThenType('Doe')
  .get('@email')
  .clearThenType('john.doe@email.com');
```

Comment: This won't work if you have to use the type() method for date and time entries. [According to the documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/type.html#Date-Inputs), while entering values into date, month, week, time fields you cannot use special characters like {backspace} {selectall} etc

Comment: Well you could set the value of the input to blank before you start typing but this seems hacky to me and I don't know the implications of doing that. 

Since the clear() command already handles the inputs you gave above, another thing you could do is create a new cypress command that just calls clear() then type() on the element. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: the new custom command won't work either, because it takes 2 parameters `(subject, text)`, but your test code is providing only one in `.clearThenType('john.doe@email.com')`

Comment: Since the previous subject option is set to true `{ prevSubject: true }` the subject will be passed into the callback automatically by Cypress.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands